# rails アプリで投稿カラムの編集や更新ができない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

#### 前提・実現したいこと

投稿カラムの title, body の編集、update ができません。
エラーがなくどこが悪いのか特定できず詰まっています。
コントローラーのupdateメソッドが毎回falseでrender :editを実行しているためだと考えましたがupdateがfalseになってしまう原因がわかりません。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

- updateできない
- book_cotrollerのupdateアクション内のupdateメソッドがfalse
- エラーメッセージなし

#### 該当のソースコード

下記の他に必要なものがあればコメントもらい次第追加します。よろしくお願いします。

---

**books_controller.rb**

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /books
  # GET /books.json
  def index
    @book = Book.new
    @books = Book.all
  end

  # GET /books/1
  # GET /books/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /books/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /books
  # POST /books.json
  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)
    if @book.save
      redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully created.'
    else
      render :index
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /books/1
  # PATCH/PUT /books/1.json
  def update
    if @book.update(book_params)
      redirect_to books_path, notice: 'Book was successfully updated.'
    else
      raise @book.error
      render :index , notice: 'update was failed'
    end
  end

  # DELETE /books/1
  # DELETE /books/1.json
  def destroy
    @book.destroy
    redirect_to books_url, notice: 'Book was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_book
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(book) do |f| %>
  <% if book.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(book.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this book from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% book.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: "book_title" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: "book_body" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<h1>Editing Book</h1>
<%= @book.body %>
<form>
  <%= render 'form',{ book: @book }%>
</form>

<%= link_to 'Show', @book, class: "show_#{@book.id}" %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', books_path, class: "back" %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :books
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

Rails 5.2.4.3

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/267262

Comment: 解決済みの様子。